# How can I allow a user to change values in a XAML datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a XAML window containing a datagrid with 8 columns. It reads two flat files and populates the datagrid with the values those files contain. (I've not included the code to do that as that works fine and isn't relevant to my question.) I want a user to be able to edit values in the "From" and "To" columns but not in any of the others. What currently happens is that when a user clicks on a cell, the entire row is highlighted (goes blue) but the cell clicked on is also highlighted with a bold border. If the user then clicks on another cell, nothing happens (except that the new row and cell are highlighted). If the user clicks again on the highlighted cell, or presses a key on the keyboard, they get the following error:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the XAML definition:

```
<Window x:Class="CrewPlanEditor.Validate"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Check Duties" Height="571" Width="753" MinWidth="674" MinHeight="431" Background="#b3d9ff" Icon="CrewPLAN.ico">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DgValidate" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontWeight="Normal" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Crew" Binding="{Binding DutyNo}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Run" Binding="{Binding BusNo}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="From" Binding="{Binding From}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="To" Binding="{Binding To}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Brk" Binding="{Binding Next}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding DutyTypeName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Depot" Binding="{Binding Depot}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding Cost}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the C# behind it:

```
using System.Windows;
using CrewPlanEditor.Contexts;
using IO = System.IO;

namespace CrewPlanEditor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Validate.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Validate
    {
        public Validate(string jobFolder)
        {
            var dutiesFile = IO.Path.Combine(jobFolder, "Data", "Duties.txt");
            var dutyTypesFile = IO.Path.Combine(jobFolder, "Data", "DutyTypes.txt");
            var duties = new DutiesFileReader().ReadFile(null, dutiesFile, dutyTypesFile).GridDutyData;
            DataContext = duties;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the type of your "GridDutyData" collection supports editing. It should implement the IList interface. HashSet<T> does not for example but List<T> and ObservableCollection do.

And if you only want the user to be able to edit the "From" and "To" columns you can set the IsReadonly property of the other columns to True:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Crew" Binding="{Binding DutyNo}" IsReadOnly="True" /> />
```

Also make sure that the "From" and "To" properties have public setters.